# Determine the timezone of NOW() in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a column `'date'` whose data type is `TIMESTAMP`.
Entries into this are made as follows:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name_1> (<othercolumns>,date)
SELECT 
  <othercolumns>,
  NOW()
FROM <table_name_2>.
```

After retrieving the `date` from this table I need to compare it to some other date say, `date2` a PHP DateTime Object. I know the timezone of `date2`. How do I determine the timezone of `date` from the table so I can compare it to `date2` correctly.

Comment: @Robby Exactly the question I was looking for. Wondered why I couldn't find that question earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It should be your MySQL server's defalt timezone.

Comment: Unless you override it on the connection level.